# What is the frame rate of the 1080p HDMI output on an iPad 3rd Generation?

Tags: video, hdmi, ipad, video-capture

I'm trying to figure out which HDMI Capture Card to buy and the cards that support 1080p60 are ten times more expensive than the ones that only does 1080i60/1080p30.

I would love to get 1080p60 out of the iPad, but I don't want to bet on this.

Also, does the HDMI out give the same fps for both apps and movies? I would like to record an app at 60 fps.

Comment: To me it's very unlikely that an iPad outputs 1080p60 but I can't find a source to confirm that.

Answer (score 1):

For HD video, Apple's page on the [specifications for iPad 3rd Generation](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP647) states (emphasis mine):

> Video formats supported: **H.264 video up to 1080p, 30 frames per second,** High Profile level 4.1 with AAC-LC audio up to 160 Kbps, 48kHz, stereo audio in .m4v, .mp4, and .mov file formats;

So if it is capable of playing *HD video up to 1080p at just 30fps,* then all that an HDMI capture card with 60fps support can do is capture at 30fps (and maybe add interpolation frames to make it 60fps). Since there's no actual gain by doing this, a 1080p30 capture card should suffice.

On the apps side, according to [benchmark tests by phonearena.com on the iPad 3rd Generation](http://www.phonearena.com/news/Apple-iPad-3-benchmark-tests_id28266), it was able to go up to 60fps (depending on the test). But note that this is just graphics rendering frame rate, not video decoding or even video recording (the latter is just 30fps according to Apple's specifications page). Video encoding (converting the app's graphics to HD) cannot be better than the video decoding support of 30fps.

I do not know if the HDMI output would be at the same frame rate for apps and video.

Comment: They're actually a bit confusing with the specifications. I thought that meant that the device only supported playback for those codecs in general, not that those codecs were the ones supported for video out.
Doesn't it support RAW 1080p output? I think I read somewhere that 720p60 is supported but their spec says nothing about that.

Would the encoding/decoding of app graphics still be a frame rate bottleneck if the app produced it's own 1080p picture (as opposed to letting the iPad downscale the app itself for video out)?